# Before action not firing when pasting in same URL with different params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, before-filter

I'm having a `before_action :slice` in my `application_controller` which slices some params and appends them to an object.

So let's say I visit https://myhomepage.com?param1=1&param2=2 it will slice these params and appends them to an array. When I'm staying on the page and I paste https://myhomepage.com?param1=1&param2=2 again it will not run the before action for whatever reason. Only if I press the reload button it will trigger the before action again with the new parameters.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: are you using a GET in both cases? I mean, if you're cut and pasting the url into the browser address textbox then you're using a GET there.

Comment: @jaydel it does not trigger a GET on the second time I paste the first params again, which is what I want

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean here. "When I'm staying on the page and I paste https://myhomepage.com?param1=5&param2=6 it will not run the before action for whatever reason" implies that you're hitting the return key after pasting? also, " Only if I press the reload button it will trigger the before action again with the new parameters." if I understand this correctly it blows my mind. Hitting the browser refresh button only reruns the query that got it to that page, not execute what's changed in the address box. can you enumerate your process more clearly, please?

Comment: ran out of space. An example of what I'm looking for is something like "1. visit page. 2. change parameters in the browser address field. 3. hit return ..."

Comment: @jaydel sure I will elaborate. I take `https://myhomepage.com?param1=1&param2=2` paste it to the address bar and press enter. Page loads and before_action gets called. Then I take `https://myhomepage.com?param1=5&param2=6 ` paste it over in the address bar and press enter. Everything as expected. But then I take `https://myhomepage.com?param1=1&param2=2` again, overpaste it and press enter, no action gets called, it just re-renders the page. Debugger doesn't stop at all in the before action.

Comment: I do not have a good answer for you, I'm sorry. Is it possible that the browser, seeing that the URL has been visited just uses the cached version of what was shown? It's just a thought...

Comment: @jaydel maybe, thats what I don't know

Comment: I went to this link concerning [browser caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) and it appears that depending on the timeout on caching it may or may not go back to the server. I don't know if you've defined caching timeout in your headers or what the default is on the browser you're using.

Comment: Sounds like caching, but Rails only caches static assets by default. If you have developer tools in your browser (Chrome has them built-in), you can look at the network logs and determine if the browser is sending a request or not, and you can also view the headers to see if there's anything cache-related in there. Possible there's something between your browser and Rails that's caching, too (web server, corporate proxy, etc).

Comment: @JimStewart slightly late but it was a caching problem. Though I can't figure out what kind of cache it is. I checked Nginx config but nothing particular. It is driving me insane